# Restricting a function to prevent divide by zero errors when used in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I have a function which I would like to fit to some data:
$$f(\nu) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{A^{2} (\nu \cos(2 \pi T \nu_{0}) \sin(2 \pi T \nu) - \nu_{0} \cos(2 \pi T \nu) \sin(2 \pi T \nu_{0}))^{2} }{\pi^{2}(\nu^{2} - \nu_{0}^{2})^{2}}\right)^{2} + n_{1}^{2}}$$

In Mathematica code this is:

```
FTCos[A_, \[Nu]0_, T_, n1_, \[Nu]_] :=Sqrt[((A^2 (\[Nu] Cos[\[Pi] T \[Nu]0] Sin[\[Pi] T \[Nu]]-\[Nu]0 Cos[\[Pi] T \[Nu]] Sin[\[Pi] T \[Nu]0])^2)/(\[Pi]^2 (\[Nu]^2-\[Nu]0^2)^2))^2 + n1^2]
```

Now when plotted this function looks perfectly happy:

```
Plot[FTCos[0.015, 65000, 32, 0.0035, \[Nu]], {\[Nu], 65000 - 0.1,  
  65000 + 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However when I want to fit the function to some data, I get divide by zero errors mainly I suspect from the $\pi^{2}(\nu^{2} - \nu_{0}^{2})^{2}$ in the denominator. Is there a away I can force `NonlinearModelFit` to not step over this range? My solution at the moment is to add a very small offset such that $\pi^{2}(\nu^{2} - (\nu_{0} + c_{0})^{2})^{2}$, where $C_{0}$ is a constant and therefore stopping divide by zero problems bu this seems crude.

Here is some sample data for the fit:

```
Data = {{64999.8, 0.000720979}, {64999.8, 0.003186}, {64999.8, 
  0.00293932}, {64999.8, 0.00316765}, {64999.8, 0.0033633}, {64999.8, 
  0.00295064}, {64999.8, 0.00186358}, {64999.9, 0.00478983}, {64999.9,
   0.00426355}, {64999.9, 0.00379112}, {64999.9, 
  0.00360024}, {64999.9, 0.00277454}, {64999.9, 0.00315563}, {65000., 
  0.00517466}, {65000., 0.00379848}, {65000., 0.029573}, {65000., 
  0.0577326}, {65000., 0.0295179}, {65000., 0.00187226}, {65000., 
  0.00293791}, {65000.1, 0.00397577}, {65000.1, 0.00400265}, {65000.1,
   0.00374722}, {65000.1, 0.00284581}, {65000.1, 
  0.00246572}, {65000.1, 0.00390391}, {65000.2, 0.00205606}, {65000.2,
   0.00175062}, {65000.2, 0.00189607}, {65000.2, 
  0.00475776}, {65000.2, 0.00331147}, {65000.2, 0.00228614}, {65000.3,
   0.00347153}}
```

And my current attempt of a fit is

```
NonlinearModelFit[Data,{FTCos[A, \[Nu]0, 32, n1, \[Nu]],{0 < A < 0.02, 0 < n1 < 0.0035,65000 - 3 12.5/800 < \[Nu]0 < 3 12.5/800 + 65000}},{{\[Nu]0, 65000}, {A, 0.015}, {n1, 0.004}}, \[Nu],MaxIterations->10000];
```

Comment: You could try to find the limit of `nu -> nu0` and then use `Piecewise` to plug the function for that particular value. Other than that, adding a small fudge factor to the denominator really isn't a bad fix as long as you verify that it doesn't change the function much overall.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit It was a good thought with the limit, I tried `Limit[FTCos[A, \[Nu]0, 32, n1, \[Nu]],\[Nu]->\[Nu]0 ]` but the result just gives me a flat line when I plot the same values. Maybe the fudge factor has to stay after all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those unique moments where immediate assignment (`=`) for functions comes in handy. Like I suggested in my comment, you can compute the limit symbolically, and then use `Piecewise` to bake the limit into the singularity of the function:

```
FTCos[A_, \[Nu]0_, T_, n1_, \[Nu]_] :=Sqrt[((A^2 (\[Nu] Cos[\[Pi] T \[Nu]0] Sin[\[Pi] T \[Nu]]-\[Nu]0 Cos[\[Pi] T \[Nu]] Sin[\[Pi] T \[Nu]0])^2)/(\[Pi]^2 (\[Nu]^2-\[Nu]0^2)^2))^2 + n1^2];

lim = Simplify[
   Limit[FTCos[A, \[Nu]0, 32, n1, \[Nu]], \[Nu] -> \[Nu]0], 
   Assumptions -> {\[Nu]0, A, n1} \[Element] Reals
];
FTCosContinuous[A_, \[Nu]0_, T_, n1_, \[Nu]_] = Piecewise[ (* Note the use of = instead of := *)
   {
    {lim, \[Nu]0 == \[Nu]},
    {FTCos[A, \[Nu]0, T, n1, \[Nu]], True}
    }
];
```

Now you have a function where you can insert the same values for `nu` and `nu0` with impunity:

```
FTCosContinuous[0.015, 65000, 32, 0.0035, 65000]
```

> 0.0577062

**edit**

The OP asked about using this function in `NonlinearModelFit`. For me, the following runs normally on version 12:

```
NonlinearModelFit[Data,
 {FTCosContinuous[A, \[Nu]0, 32, n1, \[Nu]], 
 {0 < A < 0.02, 0 < n1 < 0.0035, 65000 - 3 12.5/800 < \[Nu]0 < 3 12.5/800 + 65000}}, 
 {{\[Nu]0, 65000}, {A, 0.015}, {n1, 0.004}}, \[Nu], MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

If this doesn't work for some reason, it is always possible to define a numeric function by using an argument pattern like:

```
ClearAll[FTCosContinuous];
FTCosContinuous[A_?NumericQ, \[Nu]0_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, n1_?NumericQ, \[Nu]_?NumericQ] = ...
```

This will force `NonlinearModelFit` to only evaluate the functions for numeric arguments so that the internal structure of the function will be invisible to it. It comes at the cost of Mathematica not being able to use symbolic derivatives, though.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but is it compatible with `NonlinearModelFit`? I can't seem to implement `FTCosContinuous[A_, \[Nu]0_, T_, n1_, \[Nu]_]` as a fit function I don't think it likes conditional expressions?

Comment: In that case, try clearing and re-defining `FTCosContinuous` with the pattern `FTCosContinuous[A_, \[Nu]0_, T_, n1_, \[Nu]_?NumericQ]` to prevent it from evaluating symbolically.